# Reac: do I have to use useState to fetch datas before rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My component has to render datas from a DB. I use this snippet of code (verbose naming is here only to be explicit!):

```
let resList = [];
useEffect(() => {
    query.find().then((resultQuery) => {
        resList = createResultListFromResultQuery(resultQuery);
    });
    const createResListFromResultQuery = (resultQuery) => {
        ... // code to do format datas in the expected form -- works well
    }
});

... // below:
... // use resList to display datas in return method of component
```

When I display the `resList` inside the `useEffect` just after the function call to format datas, it's OK. But when I want to display and use outside, it doesn't work. I guess it's "normal": datas are fetched asynchronously and not available in the rendering, and because I don't use useState, there is no rendering post fetching. I can see by the way that the display outside of useEffect comes FIRST and display inside comes after...
My question is: if replace the `let resList = []` by a `useState`, it works, but is there a way to avoid using this? In fact, there is no other re-rendering on this screen after first display of datas (it is a screen to pick one of the datas and edit it...) and I don't feel it's "right" to use useState (and moreover, I read somewhere that we had to try to do without if possible).

Comment: Use state here. This is obviously an example of where to use useState. Trying to do this without state is hacky at most and won't teach you proper react methodic. Check this out: [Start thinking in react](https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react)

Comment: 'and I don't feel it's "right"', while using React you will have this feeling a lot. You might do some hacks if you really want to, but the proper way is using state. You can create your DOM inside useEffect and then attach it to some elements via vanilla JS way, but then why you even use react?